# Navigating Between DialogFragment & Fragment with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph

[image: Navigation Flow]

In the above navigation flow, I am facing an issue while navigating from `Dialog 3` to `Dialog 1` stack is not getting cleared --- so when I tap the **device back button** from `Dialog 1` then takes back to `Dialog 3` instead of going to `Fragment`.

```
     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1" />

     <dialog
        android:id="dialog1"
        android:name="dialog1"
        tools:layout="@layout/dialog1" />

     <dialog
        android:id="@+id/dialog2"
        android:name="dialog2"
        tools:layout="@layout/dialog2" />

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/dialog3"
        android:name="dialog3"
        tools:layout="@layout/dialog3">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionToDialog1"
            app:destination="@id/dialog1"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/dialog1"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </dialog>
```

On Device Back Button Tap I am having below code

```
navController.navigate(R.id.actionToDialog1);
```

FYI, navigation works fine, but once you land on `Dialog 1` stack is not getting cleared and it should go to `Fragment` instead goes to `Dialog 3`

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932672/navigation-popupto-and-popuptoinclusive-arent-clearing-the-backstack